# Electrons in graphene will behave as in 2D space?

Tags: coulombs-law, graphene

Will electrons in graphene behave as in pure 2D space, that is they interact with eachother by a Coulomb potential ~ $\ln r$ instead of $1/r$? I think many force lines will "leak" out of graphene membrane $M(x,y)$ so 2D Poisson's equation for charge distribution in graphene $\Delta V(x,y) =  - \varepsilon _0^{ - 1}\rho (x,y)$ never hold. It should be $\Delta V(x,y,z) =  - \varepsilon _0^{ - 1}\rho (x,y)\delta (z)$. Is there a 'modified 2D Poisson's equation' for graphene?

Sorry for my English!

Comment: No offence intended, but that's a big claim, imo. Have you a published source for a 2D field, or am I possibly misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I suspect the answer might depend on (or at least require knowledge of) boundary conditions, though I could be wrong.

Comment: I have to solve Poisson's equation for graphene. But if i work with 3D version, i meet a very small 3rd dimension so i ask for a 2D version of Poisson's eq for graphene. I dont think it's just simple $\Delta V(x,y) =  - \varepsilon _0^{ - 1}\rho (x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm no expert on this, but a quick literature search suggests that you are sort of correct.  [Here's a paper on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.2046) which is about this.  You shouldn't trust everything you read on arXiv because it is not peer reviewed but this paper has subsequently been published in Phys. Rev. B as

1/N expansion in correlated graphene

By: Kotov, Valeri N.; Uchoa, Bruno; Castro Neto, A. H.

PHYSICAL REVIEW B  Volume: 80   Issue: 16     Article Number: 165424

So it is probably good.  The readers digest summary is that at small distances the interaction potential is the standard Coulomb $1/r$ but for larger distances it is $\sim -\ln{(r)}$ because of "weak confinement of the electric field in the graphene plane".